# Query returning -> ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle

i'm running this query below, and oracle returning the following message: Query returning -> ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
When i uncomment the last line, it works. I think thats why this return few results. how to solve this?

```
 select substr(xmlagg(xmlelement (e, str||',')).extract ('//text()'),1,(Length(Trim(xmlagg (xmlelement (e, str||',')).extract ('//text()')))-2)) motivos
     FROM (
           select to_char(lo_valor) str
             from editor_layout el,
                  editor_versao_documento ev,
                  editor_documento ed,
                  editor_layout_campo elc,
                  editor_campo ec,
                  editor_registro er,
                  editor_registro_campo erc,
                  pw_editor_clinico pec,
                  pw_documento_clinico pdc
            where pec.cd_editor_registro   = er.cd_registro
              and pdc.cd_documento_clinico = pec.cd_documento_clinico
              and ed.cd_documento          = ev.cd_documento
              and el.cd_versao_documento   = ev.cd_versao_documento
              and el.cd_layout             = elc.cd_layout
              and elc.cd_campo             = ec.cd_campo
              and elc.cd_campo             = erc.cd_campo
              and er.cd_registro           = erc.cd_registro
              and er.cd_layout             = el.cd_layout
              and ec.ds_identificador = 'nut_orientacoes_entregues_1'
              AND To_Char(lo_valor) IS NOT null
              --and Trunc(pdc.dh_documento) BETWEEN Trunc(SYSDATE-5) AND Trunc(SYSDATE)
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the `xmlagg(xmlelement ...)` call returns a `clob`, and you are trying to stuff it into a `varchar2` since you call `substr` for example. That will fail if the `clob` is too large.

The reason it will fail when you uncomment the last line is that outside that range, there are rows having the contents that is too long.

Comment: searching on the net, i found something like this: add getClobval() after extract...
->  extract('//text()').getclobval()
so, i have the following message: ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB